# Python: Nested List Inside Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm currently stuck with this output of a nested list when trying to append the list as the definition of my dictionary.

I know this is probably more code than I should include, but I figured it's helpful to show more than less.

```
class Account:

    accountInfo = {} #ex. ID : 5FE19C (hexadecimal ID's)

    def __init__(self):
        choice = raw_input("Would you like to login or signup?\n")
        if choice.lower() == "login":
            self.login()

        elif choice.lower() == "signup":
            print "Great! Fill in the following."
            self.signup()

        else:
            self.__init__()

    def signup(self):
        import random

        accountID = '%010x' % random.randrange(16**10) # 10 digit hexadecimal ID generator
        personalInfo = []

        self.accountInfo[accountID] = []

        firstName = raw_input("First Name: ")
        lastName = raw_input("Last Name: ")
        email = raw_input("E-Mail: ")
        password = raw_input("Password: ")
        birthdate = raw_input("DOB (DD/MM/YYYY): ")
        alias = raw_input("Username/Alias: ")

        personalInfo.append(firstName)
        personalInfo.append(lastName)
        personalInfo.append(email)
        personalInfo.append(password)
        personalInfo.append(birthdate)
        personalInfo.append(alias)

        for i in range(1):
            self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)
            #creates an unwanted nested list, but the output is correct

        print self.accountInfo
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the output of a nested list in my dictionary. The contents of the dictionary are correct, but it's just that unwanted and unnecessary nested list.

output:

```
>>> {'6de7bcf201': [['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'birthdate', 'alias']]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty straight forward:

`personalInfo` is a list. You append items to it and get something like `[..,..,..]`. You initiate the value of `self.accountInfo[accountID]` also as a list. Then you append your first list to the second list, giving you a list of lists.

Instead of `self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)` try `self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
personalInfo = []  # PersonalInfo is a list
# skipped
self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)  # add list to the list
```

This is similar to

```
main = []
p_info = []
main.append(p_info)  # result would be main = [[]]
```

If you want to have just a dict inside list, change personalInfo to {}
that would requare to change personalInfo.append to personalInfo[x] = y

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how lists work, but as far as the last sentence you had goes - I want the list inside the dict, not dict inside list. :)

Answer (score 0):

`personalInfo` is a list and `self.accountInfo[accountID]` is another list.

With `self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)` you are injecting one inside the other.

You can do `self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`

And what's the point of `for i in range(1)`? It's not looping at all!

Comment: Still new to python, but I used examples from others' projects and it's just what worked at the time. I would love some guidance as to what I should do instead though!

Comment: update: realized I just needed to delete `for i in range(1)` lmfao.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! A couple of things:

Imports should generally be at the top of a file. For your `signup` 
    function, the `import random` should be at the top.

Your `__init__` shouldn't be called again on a class. `__init__` is    considered the "constructor" of the class - as such it should    generally be called once. Consider putting your `raw_input` section in another function and call that twice.

Print is a function, not a statement (your last line)

To answer your question, you have a nested list because you are making two lists. You're first building up `personalInfo` and then appending that item to the empty list you made for `accountInfo` you can have a single-level list if you just set `self.accountInfo[accountID] =`personalInfo`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :) - and I have the import random in its' current position because when imported from outside the class, it does not work. I'm assuming you're saying it should go at the top of the class method?

Comment: It shouldn't actually go in the class definition at all! Imports should go at the very top of the file - your first lines should be any imports you need!

Comment: And about the `__init__` part, I'm just getting introduced to constructors, deconstructors, etc. So that's why my code is a little amateur. Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries :) My other suggestion would be to start using python 3 rather than python 2. Python 2 is going EOL on January 1 of 2020 - it's heading out the door!

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Hey - upon fixing my mistakes I've ended up with the output containing an unwanted `[...]` at the end of the list. I can't ask another question for 90 minutes and you've been very helpful, so just figured I'd ask you here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test right now but:. 
 Replace `self.accountInfo[accountID] = []` with `self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`.  And delete `for i in range(1): self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)`